# Moving grouped MEDIAN / Get the MEDIAN of specific months from the past IN T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, grouping, median

Let's say I have a table:

| DATE | ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2010 | 1 | 100 |
| 02.2010 | 1 | 200 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 12.2010 | 1 | 300 |
| 01.2011 | 1 | 150 |
| 02.2011 | 1 | 250 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 12.2011 | 1 | 350 |
| 01.2012 | 1 | 200 |
| 02.2012 | 1 | 300 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 12.2012 | 1 | 400 |

I want to get a median of VALUE grouped by months i.e. get something like

| DATE | ID | VALUE | MEDIAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2010 | 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 02.2010 | 1 | 200 | 200 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12.2010 | 1 | 300 | 300 |
| 01.2011 | 1 | 150 | 125 = (100+150)/2 |
| 02.2011 | 1 | 250 | 225 = (200+250)/2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12.2011 | 1 | 350 | 325 = (300+350)/2 |
| 01.2012 | 1 | 200 | 150 |
| 02.2012 | 1 | 300 | 250 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12.2012 | 1 | 400 | 350 |

I have more ID in table so I would like to get this result for every ID.

I have tried doing

`SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, MONTH(Date) ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

but I get "The function 'PERCENTILE_CONT' may not have a window frame.

I've also tried the following (but also without any results):

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VALUE)
OVER (PARTITION BY Id, MONTH(Date)) 
FROM tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2 
ON tab1.key = tab2.key
WHERE tab1.Date BETWEEN Min(Date) AND tab2.Date
```

**EDIT**
So far I have resolved it with

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Date =2010 THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Date = 2010 THEN VALUE ELSE NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, MONTH(Date))  ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN Date =2011 THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Date <= 2011 THEN VALUE ELSE NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, MONTH(Date))  ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN Date =2012 THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Date <= 2012 THEN VALUE ELSE NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, MONTH(Date))  ELSE 0 END)
FROM tab1
```

But to be honest, I would like to have an resolution without assumption of a priori knowledge of dates. I've thought about WHILE LOOP and updating column while @MinYear <= @MaxYear where in every iteration @MinYear = @MinYear+1 but in this case I would have to create temporary tables which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use (Value1+value2)/2 as median as your requirement is little complicated.

```
 CREATE TABLE MedianData
  (   
  [Date] VARCHAR(100)
  ,ID INT 
  ,[Value] INT
 )

 INSERT INTO MedianData VALUES  ('01.2010', 1,  100)
    ,('02.2010',    1,  200)
    ,('12.2010',    1,  300)
    ,('01.2011',    1,  150)
    ,('02.2011',    1,  250)
    ,('12.2011',    1,  350)
    ,('01.2012',    1,  200)
    ,('02.2012',    1,  300)
    ,('12.2012',    1,  400)

 SELECT * 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER  ( PARTITION BY  Substring([Date],1,2 ) ORDER BY [Date]  ) AS [row]
       ,Substring([Date],1,2 ) as [MONTH]
    INTO #Temp_tbl2
   FROM MedianData 

 SELECT
    A.Date
    ,A.ID
    ,A.[Value] 
   --Logic is applied here. I used (Value1+value2)/2 as median
   ,CASE WHEN A.[row] = 3   THEN  ( A.[Value] +  (    SELECT T.[Value] FROM #Temp_tbl2 
                    T where T.[MONTH] =  Substring(A.[Date],1,2 ) AND T.[row]  = 1 ) )/2 
    WHEN  A.[row] != 1 THEN  (A.total/2) 
    ELSE A.total END as [Median]
   INTO #Temp_table
  FROM
    (
     SELECT * 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER  ( PARTITION BY  Substring([Date],1,2 ) ORDER BY [Date]  ) AS [row] 

     ,SUM ([Value] )   OVER  (  PARTITION BY  Substring([Date],1,2 ) ORDER BY [Date] ) AS [total] 
       FROM MedianData
    ) AS A

  --to make the table data order
    SELECT MedianData.*, #Temp_table.Median
    FROM MedianData
    INNER JOIN #Temp_table
         ON MedianData.[Date] =  #Temp_table.[Date] 

  drop table #Temp_table
  drop table #Temp_tbl2
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I haven't tried it on my set because of resolution I got but this looks great also. Thank you for your answer!